# Publish Office Add-in on Office 365 in Organization

Tags: azure, sharepoint, ms-word, office365, office-js

I have just published my Office Word Add-in to Sharepoint App Catalog as below:

[image]

My add-in application is already deployed on Azure web app. When using Sharepont Word online, I can add that add-in in the menu Insert/Office Add-ins then go to My Organization tab. It works perfectly.

[image]

The problem is when I sign out and relog in or switch to another account, the add-in is disappeared and I have to add it again (go to menu Insert/Office Add-ins). Is there any way to keep the add-in there for next time use?
I found out that if I install an add-ins in store tab (instead of My Organization tab), it still be there even I log out or switch to other account

Comment: anyone? Please help :(

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the question!

Unfortunately the way Add-Ins work with the Add-In Catalog they will need to be added each time
The store add-ins your referencing are using a new feature called Add-In Commands that adds the Add-In to the ribbon. Unfortunately Add-In commands are not supported for Add-Ins available through the Add-In Catalog

For the kind of functionality you're looking for we'd recommend the Centralized Deployment feature https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Deploy-Office-Add-ins-in-the-Office-365-Admin-Center-737e8c86-be63-44d7-bf02-492fa7cd9c3f

Thanks
Phil

Comment: Centralized Deployment also have a problem like the Sharepoint Cataloug. The icon still disapeared when i log out or switch account.